# RasPi not triggering on ARP Probe

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, arp

I'm trying to learn about programming and working in command line and all that and I'm still really new at it. I got an Amazon Dash button to mess around with and I was able to get it to trigger a message in a Slack room when you press it. Then I tried recreated the program on my raspi2, it worked ONCE and now when I run the program it just seems to not recognize the MAC address, ie nothing happens at all.

Here is the program that is running

```python
import requests
import json

SLACK_INCOMING_WEB_HOOK = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/....." #Figure I should remove this for my question...
SLACK_INCOMING_USER = "SlackBit Bot" #Slack Bot display name
SLACK_INCOMING_CHANNEL = "#test" #Slack Channel

from scapy.all import *
def arp_display(pkt):
  if pkt[ARP].op == 1: #who-has (request)
    if pkt[ARP].psrc == '0.0.0.0': # ARP Probe
      if pkt[ARP].hwsrc == 'a0:02:dc:42:32:e3': # Huggies
        print "Pushed Doritos"
        payload = {
            "text": "You Pressed The Button!",
            "username": SLACK_INCOMING_USER,
            "channel": SLACK_INCOMING_CHANNEL
        }
        r = requests.post(SLACK_INCOMING_WEB_HOOK, json.dumps(payload), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
        print r.status_code
        print r.content
      else:
        print "ARP Probe from unknown device: " + pkt[ARP].hwsrc

print sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, count=0)
```

It worked the very first time I ran the program and pressed the button, but now it just runs and does nothing indefinitely.

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if my terminology is all wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the packet look which you are trying to filter?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not even sure how to answer that, sorry :/ All I know is that it worked as expected the very first time I ran it and then never again.

Comment: So, I know nothing about how dash works, but in general, you should only see that arp request once and then the client should cache it until things time out... can you / have you tried restarting the dash hardware?  Have you tried sniffing the traffic to see if there is other data sent besides arp requests?

Comment: @foon by design, the dash actually shuts off and disconnects from the wifi between presses. So as far as I know it should make the request every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line:

```
if pkt[ARP].psrc == '0.0.0.0': # ARP Probe
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two brand new dash buttons, instead of doing an arp for 0.0.0.0, they are doing a bootp request to get a dhcp address, this causes the common scripts that are looking for an arp 0.0.0.0 to ignore them.

you can modify the scripts to watch for bootp, instead of watching for arp 0.0.0.0, or just, as cyrus says, comment out the line testing for an arp probe.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with this change (Detecting the Dash button with bootp vs. arp), here's what I'm using with a brand new Dash button:

```
from scapy.all import *
import requests
import time
def arp_display(pkt):
  if pkt.haslayer(DHCP):
   if pkt[Ether].src == 'x:x:x:x:x:x': # Dash Button MAC
    print "Pushed Dash Button" 
   else: 
    print "BOOTP Request from other device: " + pkt[Ether].src
print sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="(udp and (port 67 or 68))", store=0)
```